# assign slot component props before render method

Tags: reactjs, react-props, children

I have a parent component with mutiple slot components. I'm searching for a way to assign the slot component props outside the slot defintion to make it more readable.

This is my example component:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <ParentComponent
      child1={<Child1 child1Props={child1Props} />}
      child2={<Child2 child2Props={child2Props} />}
    />
  );
};
```

This would be one possible solution but is this a legit way?

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const child1 = <Child1 child1Props={child1Props} />;
  const child2 = <Child2 child2Props={child2Props} />;

  return <ParentComponent child1={child1} child2={child2} />;
};
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, that is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a object for it and then spread it in `ParentComponent` props

like this :

```
const Component = (props) => {

  const children = {
    child1:<Child1 child1Props={child1Props} />,
    child2:<Child2 child1Props={child2Props} />,
  }

  return <ParentComponent {...children} />;
};
```

or use createElement:

```
import { createElement } from 'react';

const Component = props => {
  const children = {
    child1: createElement(Child1, child1Props),
    child2: createElement(Child2, child2Props),
  };

  return <ParentComponent {...children} />;
};
```